# Create a backoffice user with access to editing for page and pagetype

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have a requirement whereby we need to create a backoffice user with access to only creating the page and pagetype level attributes and access them and edit them. Should we use the table Employee or User,and what user group to map this user to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your own user group with page permission. It must be Employee type, User type for customer.